# Comparação entre variáveis de strpos() - PHP

Tags: php, variáveis, session, comparação

Estou precisando de uma ajuda entre níveis de acesso, vou postar parte do código.
É uma conexão no AD (Active Diretory), autenticando o usuário e buscando ao qual grupo ele pertence.

**Esse o código de login.php**

```
    <?php
    include("auth.php");

    // check to see if user is logging out
    if(isset($_GET['out'])) {
        // destroy session
        session_unset();
        $_SESSION = array();
        unset($_SESSION['username'],$_SESSION['access']);
        session_destroy();
    }

    // check to see if login form has been submitted
    if(isset($_POST['username'])){
        // run information through authenticator
        if(authenticate($_POST['username'],$_POST['userPassword']))
        {
            header("Location: assets/procge.php");
            die();
        } else {
            $error = 1;
        }
    }

    ?>


<form action="#" class="form-signin" method="POST">

<h2 style="text-align:center; font-size: 18px;">Para acesso Telas BI, <br />realize o login.</h2>
<?php
if(isset($error)) echo "<div style='color:#ff0000; text-align:center;'>ERRO!<br /> Usuário e senha inválidos ou sem acesso.</div><br />";
if(isset($_GET['out'])) echo "Sucesso ao deslogar!!!";
 ?>
 <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Usuário</label>
<input id="username" type="text" name="username" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuário" /> 
 <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Senha</label>
<input type="password" name="userPassword" id="password" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha">   
<input class="btn btn-success"  name="submit" value="Acessar" type="submit">
</form>
```

**Aqui a tela de Auth.php**

```
<?php
function authenticate($username, $password) {
    if(empty($username) || empty($password)) return false;

$adServer = "ldap://10.10.100.23";
    $ldap = ldap_connect($adServer);
    $ldaprdn = 'dominio' . "\\" . $username;
    $grupolda = 'DC=dominio,DC=com,DC=br';
    $grupo1 = 'grupo1';
    $grupo2 = 'grupo2';

    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

    $bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $ldaprdn, $password);

    if ($bind) {
        $filter="(sAMAccountName=$username)";
        $attr = array("memberof");
        $result = ldap_search($ldap,"$grupolda",$filter);
        ldap_sort($ldap,$result,"sn");

        $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
          for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++)      {
            if($info['count'] > 1)
                break;
           echo "<p>Acesso ao A.D. <strong> ". $info[$i]["givenname"][0]." ".$info[$i]["sn"][0] ."</strong><br /> </p>\n";

            $userDn = $info[$i]["distinguishedname"][0];
          }

          // check os grupos
             foreach($info[0]['memberof'] as $grps) {


    $access = 0;
    if(strpos($grps, $grupo1) !== false) {
    //Se pertence a esse grupo da acesso 1, somente a esse grupo
    $access += 1;   
    }

    elseif(strpos($grps, $grupo2) !== false) { 
    //Se pertence a esse grupo da acesso 2, somente a esse grupo    
    $access += 2;
    break;
    } 

      }
        if($access != 0) {
            // Cria as sessões do usuário
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['access'] = $access;
            return true;

        } else {
            $_SESSION['loginErro'] = $erro;
            // Sem direitos
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        // Usuário e senha inválidos
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Quando o usuário está em somente um dos grupos, funciona, 
se pertence ao grupo1 leva a página do grupo1,
Se pertence ao grupo2 leva a página do grupo2.

Mas quando pertence ao dois grupos grupo1e2 com acesso 3, ele sempre retorna a um dos acessos, levando a uma página individual e não a página que deve dar acesso 3.

Se alguém puder dar uma orientação de como proceder

**Esse é o procge.php**

```
<?php
// initialize session
session_start();

    if($_SESSION['access'] == 1){
            header("Location:../grupo1/index.php");
            }
    if($_SESSION['access'] == 2){
            header("Location: ../grupo2/index.php");
            }
    if($_SESSION['access'] == 3){
            header("Location: ../grupo1e2/index.php");
            }
     else{
            $_SESSION['access'] !== "Erro! Sem permissão de acesso.";
         break;
                header("Location: ../index.php");
            }

?>
```

Esse o login:

Comment: Já tentou trocar `&` por `&&` quando verifica se o usuário pertence aos dois grupos? Aliás, qual é o valor de `$grps`? Se ele iniciar com `ACESSO_1` ou `ACESSO_2`, a função `strpos` irá retornar 0 e para o `if` isso será falso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php) busca um texto em outro e retorna a posição do início se encontrar ou `false` caso contrário. O problema de se fazer:

```
if (strpos($x, $y)) { ... }
```

É que se o valor de `$x` começar com o valor de `$y`, a função retornará 0 e o interpretador do PHP irá considerar como falso, mesmo que tenha sido encontrado o texto. Veja o exemplo:

```
var_dump(strpos("Stack Overflow em Português", "Stack"));
```

O retorno será `int(0)`. Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/HLqqP0).

O correto a se fazer é verificar se o retorno não é falso. Ou seja:

```
if (strpos($x, $y) !== false) { ... }
```

Assim, mesmo que o retorno seja 0, a condição será verdadeira. No seu caso, é possível simplificar apenas para duas condições:

```
$access = 0;

if (strpos($grps, $grupo1) !== false) {
    $access += 1;
}

if (strpos($grps, $grupo2) !== false) {
    $access += 2;
}
```

Se o usuário pertencer aos dois grupos, a variável `$access` valerá 3, pois as duas condições serão verdadeiras.

---

Se existirem muitos grupos, será mais fácil trabalhar com valores binários do que inteiros. Por exemplo, vamos supor que há três grupos, então você faz a condição:

```
$access = 0;

if (strpos($grps, $grupo1) !== false) {
    $access += 1;
}

if (strpos($grps, $grupo2) !== false) {
    $access += 2;
}

if (strpos($grps, $grupo3) !== false) {
    $access += 3;
}
```

Mas a outra página da aplicação foi acessada por um usuário com `access` igual a 3. E agora, ele está apenas no grupo 3 ou está nos grupos 1 e 2? Ambas as situações iriam resultar em `$access = 3`. Sem usar a lógica da soma, seria possível definir um valor diferente para cada situação: se está apenas no grupo 3 o valor 3 e se está nos grupos 1 e 2 o valor 4. Mas e se estiver nos grupos 1 e 3? Outro valor, 5. E se estiver nos grupos 2 e 3? Outro valor, 6. E se estiver nos grupos 1, 2 e 3? Outro valor, 7. Consegue imaginar a quantidade de `if`? Imagina então se existirem 4 grupos.

Trabalhando com valores binários, você define uma potência de 2 para cada grupo. Por exemplo: grupo 1 é o valor 1 (2^0), o grupo 2 é o valor 2 (2^1) e o grupo 3 é o valor 4 (2^2). Se houvesse mais grupos seriam 8 (2^3), 16 (2^4), 32 (2^5), etc. Assim, você faz as seguintes condições:

```
$access = 0;

if (strpos($grps, $grupo1) !== false) {
    $access |= 1;
}

if (strpos($grps, $grupo2) !== false) {
    $access |= 2;
}

if (strpos($grps, $grupo3) !== false) {
    $access |= 4;
}
```

Apenas trocando o operador `+=` para `|=`, que é o ou binário. Assim, para verificar se o usuário pertence a algum grupo, basta fazer o "e binário" com o valor do grupo.

```
if ($access & 1) { ... }  // Pertence ao grupo 1
if ($access & 2) { ... }  // Pertence ao grupo 2
if ($access & 4) { ... }  // Pertence ao grupo 3
```

E pode mesclar os valores também:

```
if ($access & 3) { ... }  // Pertence aos grupos 1 e 2
if ($access & 5) { ... }  // Pertence aos grupos 1 e 3
if ($access & 6) { ... }  // Pertence aos grupos 2 e 3
if ($access & 7) { ... }  // Pertence aos grupos 1, 2 e 3
```

Comment: Baita aula, explicação nota 10, irei verificar e estudar a sua resposta e assim que possivel, irei retornar, por enqto obrigado @Anderson Carlos Woss

Comment: @MarceloRossi e funcionou?

Comment: Não!!! estou a manhã toda aqui! vou tentar postar um resposta melhorando a minha pergunta.

Comment: @MarceloRossi não faça isso. Utilize o [editar] da própria pergunta para adicionar informações relevantes.

Comment: -  editei a minha pergunta e inseri o codigo completo. ainda está me retornando somente 1 das telas. agradeço se me ajudar.

Comment: @MarceloRossi e qual é o valor de `$grps` no teste que você fez? E não utilize `else if`. Veja que na minha resposta são dois `if` separados.

Comment: $gprs é $info[0]['memberof'] - ou memberof (usuário)

Comment: Mas qual o valor da variável?

Comment: é a `$info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);` = `$info[0]['memberof']` - que busca os resultados no ` $result = ldap_search($ldap,"$grupolda",$filter);´ - e faz o filtro buscando o usuário no grupo pelo username `$filter="(sAMAccountName=$username)";`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61559/discussion-between-anderson-carlos-woss-and-marcelo-rossi).

Comment: RESOLVIDO - graças ao @Anderson Carlos Woss - simplesmente inserimos o `$access = 0;` antes do for, pois se estiver dentro do for sempre ira retornar 0.

Comment: tudo bem Carlos, voltando aqui neste problema, como faço para adicionar mais 2 grupos a esse processo?
`Acesso 1 = Grupo 1 | 
Acesso 2 = Grupo 2 | 
Acesso 3 = Grupo 1 e  Grupo 2 | 
Acesso 4 = Grupo 4 | 
Acesso 5 = Grupo 5 |
Acesso 6 = Grupo 4 e Grupo 5 | 
Acesso 7  = Grupo 1 e Grupo 2 e grupo 4 e Grupo 5`.

Tentei usar o `|=` no acesso não deu certo, e não compreendi o processo de usar o `&`, isso é para usar no procge.php - Poderia me esclarecer melhor como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Desculpe te remarcar novamente, segue minha duvida na pergunta acima.

Comment: @MarceloRossi eu já havia comentado isso na resposta: o grupo 4 deverá possuir o valor 8 e o grupo 5 o valor 16.

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite!

Bom, vamos lá, creio que o seu erro esteja na hora de checar se o usuário pertence aos dois grupos (& ao inves de &&) e, além disso, você dá um break no loop caso seja a terceira opção (1 e 2). Mas, independente disso, por que você não usa if/elseif/elseif/else ao invés dos três ifs seguidos? Em termos de desempenho, o seu programa checa as 3 condições todas as vezes que é rodado. Se ele tivesse if/elseif/elseif/else, ele checaria a primeira condição apenas uma vez e, se ela fosse verdadeira, não checaria as outras, evitando gasto de memória desnecessário.

Reescrevendo seu código (com o erro corrigido) ele ficaria assim:

```
    // tenho 2 grupos
     $grupo1 = 'ACESSO_1';
     $grupo2 = 'ACESSO_2';

    // check as informações do usuário e informa o grupo ao qual ele pertence
    foreach($info[0]['memberof'] as $grps) {


    // Verifica os grupos que pertence
    if(strpos($grps, $grupo1) && strpos($grps, $grupo2)) { 

    //se pertence ao 2 grupos da acesso aos 2 grupos acesso 3
    $access = 3; 
    } 
    elseif(strpos($grps, $grupo2)) { 

    //Se pertence a esse grupo da acesso 2, somente a esse grupo    
    $access = 2;
    } 
    elseif(strpos($grps, $grupo1)) {

    //Se pertence a esse grupo da acesso 1, somente a esse grupo
    $access = 1;   
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['loginErro'] = $erro;
        // Sem direitos
        return false;
    }

    //Se o nível de acesso for diferente de 0 cria a sessão.
    // Cria as sessões do usuário
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['access'] = $access;
    return true;

} else {
    // Usuário e senha inválidos
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Na sua lógica, se o usuário pertencer aos dois grupos, só entraria no primeiro `if`, definindo `$access = 1`, deixando ele apenas no grupo 1. Ou seja, não funciona. Aliás, o código não resolve o problema da pergunta quando utilizado `strpos`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss verdade, mas é só alterar a ordem dos ifs

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não tinha visto seu comentário na pergunta do autor, bem observado. Se fosse criada uma variavel $grupo3 = "ACESSO_1 ACESSO_2"; e feito o if com apenas uma condição não resolveria?

Comment: Como assim "apenas uma condição"?

Comment: Resolvido como o @AndersonCarlosWoss, indicou.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss - Não desmarquei, a resposta correta é a de baixo, a qual já estava marcada. E votei nas duas respostas, pois ambas me ajudaram no resultado, muito obrigado.